# Selecting specific line of a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string, that when logged returns the following:

```
console.log(string);
```

Console output:

```
956880,538,1576845
937145,45,65527
871995,40,39577
590049,66,543073
793400,58,227923
992767,40,40419
1323816,14,2322
-1,1,9
```

Now my question here is, is there a way to select a specific line from that string and only display that? Example, I want to extract the third line and save it in another variable.
So that:

```
console.log(anotherString);
```

Console output:

```
871995,40,39577
```

Also these numbers change so doing something like replace will not benefit.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why is your string printed in next lines? Have you added \n between your string?

Comment: I am extracting from a website with cheerio and request, yes there is a \n everytime theres a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string really does have multiple lines there is an invisible character which denotes the newline. This is sometimes a single `\n` and sometimes a `\r\n`. Assuming the former, you simply split using that character as the delimiter and you get an array - then pick the one you want:

```js
var input = "956880,538,1576845\n" +
"937145,45,65527\n" +
"871995,40,39577\n" +
"590049,66,543073\n" +
"793400,58,227923\n" +
"992767,40,40419\n" +
"1323816,14,2322\n" +
"-1,1,9";

var split = input.split("\n");
console.log(split[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the output is same every time, you could split the string by '\n' and then print the value. Like:

```
var str = "956880,538,1576845
           937145,45,65527
           871995,40,39577
           590049,66,543073
           793400,58,227923
           992767,40,40419
           1323816,14,2322
           -1,1,9";

var splitArray = str.split('\n'); // This will become an array now

console.log(splitArray[2]);
```